# Ctrl + Spacebar Causes Issues Between Linux and Minecraft

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, java, minecraft

Sorry for the nooby question, tonight is my first night ever trying Linux. I figured out how to install and get Minecraft running. However, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, the mouse appears in the middle of the screen and the game loses focus, flickers, and sometimes pauses.

This is important because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is sprinting and jumping in many games. I'm not sure what I should be looking up (though I tried) to learn how to fix this, and how to fix similar problems in the future. Could someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: this sounds like you are running a program in background which uses `ctrl+space` by default. can you give us some more information about what system you are running, which applications, etc...?

Comment: Whoops, of course. I am running Kubuntu 14.04 on a desktop with an AMD 6300 6-core processor, 32GB of RAM, and a Radeon R7 370 graphics card. I followed tutorials to install Java Oracle 8 and Minecraft, along with Chromium, Steam, Skype, and Terminator. All of these programs were running at the same time, on a secondary monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should figure out what action is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

You need to list all key bindings. This line should show you all bindings:

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more
```

There are some exceptions e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> this is hard-coded in Unity so you can't change it and it's not shown by this command.

Comment: Mofty, I don't know what IBus is (I will look it up), but I see the only hotkey it uses is Ctrl + Space. I just changed that. It works perfect now, thank you!